# Under Linux can the controller on an SD card reorder writes?

Tags: linux, kernel, embedded-linux, sd-card

I have a custom imx6 board that has the root filesystem on a SD card. I've received reports from customers about corrupted SD cards and I'm trying to figure out what small-invasive actions I can take to fix this problem. We're investigating things such as higher-quality SD-cards; characterizing the number of writes (should be very low but we need to verify that); verifying that the system is shutdown orderly, allowing all transactions to be written to disk; and investigating if the filesystem can be mounted readonly.

At the moment I've received little information so I can't pinpoint the exact causes and I haven't been able to reproduce the problem on my desk.

One thing I noticed is that the ext3 root filesystem is mounted with `barrier=0`. Jonathan Corbets LWN article [Barriers and Journaling Filesystems](https://lwn.net/Articles/283161/) mentions that barriers are needed to guarantee file system consistency, since disk I/O-controllers can reorder writes. But the examples there are for large datacenter disks with large workloads. Do the small I/O-controllers onboard the SD-cards reorder writes as well?

Comment: *"Do the small I/O-controllers onboard the SD-cards reorder writes as well?"* -- Yes, but it depends on the card and can be disabled.  See section 4.19 Command Queue of the SD Specifications, Part 1, Physical Layer Simplified Spec, available from sdcard.org.  Linux kernel is aware of the command queue; see **drivers/mmc/core/queue.c**.

Comment: @sawdust Ah, Looks like Linux command queue support is recently added (2017): https://lwn.net/Articles/738160/.  From what I read on the tubes, the card most support the A2 Application Performance Class in order to use command queues. A2  was addded in the 6.0 version of the SD spec (also 2017). I'm running a 3.0 kernel from 2011, so I guess I can rule out write reordering then?

Comment: I would also check the SD cards themselves to see if they have Performance Enhancement Function and CQ Support.